# SQL Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2, case

I've the following SQL Query

```
select catalogid, numitems, allitems - numitems ignoreditems
 from (
  select i.catalogid," 
    sum(case when (ocardtype in ('PayPal','Sofort') OR
                   ocardtype in ('mastercard','visa') and
                   odate is not null) AND NOT EXISTS (select CAST(booked AS INT) FROM bookedordersids b where b.booked = o.orderid)
                   then numitems
                   else 0 end) numitems,
    sum(numitems) allitems
  from orders o
  join oitems i on i.orderid=o.orderid
  group by i.catalogid
 ) X
```

and it gives me the following error

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregat or a subquery
```

When I remove the following line it works fine

```
AND NOT EXISTS (select CAST(booked AS INT) FROM bookedordersids b where b.booked = o.orderid)
```

but it's important to do this check; how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just move the aggregation one level out.
While the query can be rewritten in your case, I think it best to express it this way so you can easily understand and reuse the pattern.

```
select catalogid, sum(numitems) numitems, sum(allitems) - sum(numitems) ignoreditems
 from (
  select i.catalogid,
    case when (ocardtype in ('PayPal','Sofort') OR
                   ocardtype in ('mastercard','visa') and
                   odate is not null) AND NOT EXISTS (
      select *
      FROM bookedordersids b
      where b.booked = o.orderid)
                   then numitems
                   else 0 end
    numitems,
    numitems allitems
  from orders o
  join oitems i on i.orderid=o.orderid
 ) X
group by catalogid
```